# for loop not looping right way android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, loops, for-loop

I am developing an app in that i am adding one by one images to firebaseFirestore and getting download url of that image and save that url in to a list but my for loop not looping correctly it run sometime 1 index then 0 index and this type wrong way at last it run all index but not in one way.
Here the value of final print then value of it is some time 1 then 0 this type it runs. Please help. My code is

```
     for (int i = 0; i < mViewModel.getProductImages().getValue().size(); i++){

        Uri uri1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(mViewModel.getProductImages().getValue().get(i)));
        String fileExt = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri1.toString());

        StorageReference mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Product Images").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child(productId).child("Image" + i + "." + fileExt);
        int finalI = i;
        mStorageReference.putFile(uri1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    mStorageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Log.d("TAG", finalI + " " + task.getResult().toString());
                                imagesAdded.add(finalI, task.getResult().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because FirebaseStorage uploads your images asynchronously.
Here is a sample:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        final int counter = i;
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello" + counter);
            }
        }.start();
 }
```

this is like your problem, this will print the numbers out of order, but if you use a lock like below, it would fix the problem:

```
Object lock = new Object();
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    final int counter = i;
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello" + counter);
            synchronized (lock){
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    synchronized (lock){
    try {
          lock.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

}